# Add to a float from the back in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a user entered variable that's a float. The only rule is that it have at least a thousands decimal place and at most a hundred thousandths. A constant 100 needs to be added to each number from the back when it comes in, like this:

`1.8765` becomes `1.8865`, `104.233` becomes `104.333`, and `100.900` becomes `101.000`, etc.

It has become apparent the problem is not as easy as it sounds. Is there a python library that helps do this? This is for a program that works with Forex quotes.

Comment: Why does 1.8765 turn into 1.8865 (and not 1.9765)?

Comment: @frostnational: I believe, the last three digits need to be increased by 100

Comment: @frostnational because the `7` is the third digit from right.

Comment: If these values are already parsed as `float` objects, what you want cannot be done. `float` values are *approximations*, you have `1.87650000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`, not `1.8765`.

Comment: One possible way is to try and subtract the old value from the new value and then add the result to the old value with the required increment

Comment: If these values are still strings, we can talk; remove the decimal point, convert to *integer*, add 100, reformat to string and re-add decimal point.

Comment: By the way? why do you want to do this? It does not seem to serve any logical purpose.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters: OP cannot convert to integer, because after removing the floating point, the number is at least 1000-decimal digit-long.

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't think that's what 'hundred thousandths decimal place' means

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: So how do you interpret "at least a thousands decimal place" then?

Comment: @barakmanos: I believe the first digit after the 'dot' is the tens, followed by the hundreds and so forth.

Comment: @barakmanos: I stated that *If these values are still strings*. They are string of 6 or 7 characters. The OP stated there are at most 4 digits after the decimal point. Convert **just the digits** to an integer number, adding 100 will increment the correct digits, then make it a string again and re-add the decimal point.

Comment: This is for a program that works with Forex quotes. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need a library to do it, it can be done simply by converting the number to strings, then integers and then back to float again after adding 100.

```
x = 1.8765
dp = str(x).index('.')
y = str(int(str(x).replace('.', '')) + 100)
z = float(y[:dp] + '.' + y[dp:])
print z
# 1.8865
```

But this method may not work well always, because of the precision errors of `float` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

give the input as strings and then do some operations on it as shown.

```
def magic(temp):
    index=temp.find('.')
    temp=temp.replace('.','')
    length=len(temp)
    temp=int(temp)+100
    length2=len(str(temp))
    while(length>length2):
        temp=temp*10
        length2+=1
    return temp/float(pow(10,length-index))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> a="1.8765"  
>>> magic(a)
1.8865

>>> b="104.233"
>>> magic(b)
104.333

>>> c="100.900"
>>> magic(c)
101.0
```